# C# can't access another class variable

Tags: c#, forms, class

I'm unable to access something from one of my classes and use it in another. It has no idea what I'm talking about when I type the name of the object. How do I read between classes?

My code:
In the first class:

```
public class Form1 
{
    public struct TriangleDrawer 
    {
        // ...
        public Color Vert1Color;
        // ...
    }

    TriangleDrawer myTriangle = new TriangleDrawer();
    myTriangle.Vert1Color = Color.Red;
}
```

In the second class:

```
public class TriangleWindow: Form1 
{
    void WhateverVoid() 
    {
        GL.Color3(myTriangle.Vert1Color);
    }
}
```

`Form1` does not contain a definition for `myTriangle.Vert1Color`

Comment: `myTriangle.Vert1Color = Color.Red;` can't compile like that since it doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378511/getting-values-from-method-from-other-form. Note that public fields are a poor decision choice, so a public property is a better way to go. If you need more specific help, post a new question in which you've included a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, along with a clear, detailed explanation of what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't specify an access modifier (public, private, etc.), the declared member will have the most strict possibility. In this case, `myTriangle` will be `private`, which means that only the own class will be able to access it.

If you want derived classes to access it, you must declare it as `protected`. Of course, if you want the whole world to access it, declare it `public`, but beware, that's not a good idea with your code as is. You should use accessors (`get` and `set`) so you have some control of what will occur to that variable. Basically, if you make it `public` and then its value is not what you expected, it will be harder to find out why.

Some links you should read:

[Accessibility Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

[Using Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the 'myTriangle' field as public in order to access it from another class. Or declare it internal if both classes are in the same namespace.

Answer (score -1):

make `myTriangle` as public/protected property, default is private and you can't access it even with sub classes

```
public class Form1
{
    public TriangleDrawer MyTriangle { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do as below

```
 public class TriangleWindow : Form1
    {
        void WhateverVoid()
        {
            GL.Color3(MyTriangle.Vert1Color);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why make it public if only the subclass is using it? Should be protected.

Comment: @Rob Yes, OP can decide whether using private or public, depending on requirements